# how to connect to PostgreSQL on flutter

Tags: android, ios, database, postgresql, flutter

I'm trying to connect postgreSQL using a plutter.
I have a problem during practice, so I'm posting a question.
Below is the code I wrote.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:postgres/postgres.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: LoginPage(),
    );
  }
}

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final PostgreSQLConnection _connection = PostgreSQLConnection(
    'localhost',
    5432,
    'TEST',
    username: 'mk',
    password: '',
  );

  LoginPage({super.key});

  @override
  LoginPageState createState() => LoginPageState();
}

class LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  final TextEditingController _IDController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _passwdController = TextEditingController();

  Future<void> _login() async {
    final String ID = _IDController.text;
    final String passwd = _passwdController.text;

    try {
      await widget._connection.open();

      final List<List<dynamic>> results = await widget._connection.query(
        'SELECT * FROM table',
        substitutionValues: {
          'ID': ID,
          'passwd': passwd,
        },
      );

      if (results.isNotEmpty) {
        
        print('success');
      } else {
        
        print('fail');
      }
    } finally {
      await widget._connection.close();
    }
  }
```

Test method
First, if i enter the correct ID and password and press the login button, 'success' will come out well.
Assume that either the second ID or the secret number is incorrect and press the login button to get 'fail'.
The problem is that the following error occurs when i enter the correct ID or password after the login failure.

```
E/flutter (10970): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PostgreSQLSeverity.error : Attempting to reopen a closed connection. Create a instance instead
E/flutter (10970): #0      PostgreSQLConnection.open
connection.dart:178
E/flutter (10970): #1      LoginPageState._login
main.dart:42
E/flutter (10970): #2      _InkResponseState.handleTap
ink_well.dart:1154
E/flutter (10970): #3      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback
recognizer.dart:275
E/flutter (10970): #4      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp
tap.dart:654
E/flutter (10970): #5      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp
tap.dart:311
E/flutter (10970): #6      BaseTapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer
tap.dart:244
E/flutter (10970): #7      PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent
recognizer.dart:630
E/flutter (10970): #8      PointerRouter._dispatch
pointer_router.dart:98
E/flutter (10970): #9      PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes.<anonymous closure>
pointer_router.dart:143
E/flutter (10970): #10     _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:625:13)
E/flutter (10970): #11     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes
pointer_router.dart:141
E/flutter (10970): #12     PointerRouter.route
E/flutter (10970): #13     GestureBinding.handleEvent
binding.dart:488
E/flutter (10970): #14     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent
binding.dart:468
E/flutter (10970): #15     RendererBinding.dispatchEvent
binding.dart:333
E/flutter (10970): #16     GestureBinding._handlePointerEventImmediately
binding.dart:413
E/flutter (10970): #17     GestureBinding.handlePointerEvent
binding.dart:376
E/flutter (10970): #18     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue
binding.dart:323
E/flutter (10970): #19     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket
binding.dart:292
E/flutter (10970): #20     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:186:13)
E/flutter (10970): #21     PlatformDispatcher._dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:424:7)
E/flutter (10970): #22     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:119:31)
```

dependencies:
postgres: ^2.6.2

How do we solve it?

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message you are trying to reopen a connection closed your `_login` function, you have to modify your code to create a new connection instead of reusing the same instance.

```
Future<void> _login() async {
  final String ID = _IDController.text;
  final String passwd = _passwdController.text;

  PostgreSQLConnection connection = PostgreSQLConnection(
    'localhost',
    5432,
    'TEST',
    username: 'mk',
    password: '',
  );

  try {
    await connection.open();

    final List<List<dynamic>> results = await connection.query(
      'SELECT * FROM table',
      substitutionValues: {
        'ID': ID,
        'passwd': passwd,
      },
    );

    if (results.isNotEmpty) {
      print('success');
    } else {
      print('fail');
    }
  } finally {
    await connection.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank to you, it's been resolved! Have a nice day!!